# appbar disapear on production on flutter 3.16.3 for no raezon

Tags: ios, flutter, scaffolding, appbar

I have a app that simply log in and then when drawing the appbar disapear from the scaffold for no raseon posblie , and is only on release on testfly , what could posible happen for the app bar to disapear

```
class SecurityChallengeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecurityChallengeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecurityChallengeView> createState() => _SecurityChallengeViewState();
}

class _SecurityChallengeViewState extends State<SecurityChallengeView> {
  late SecurityChallengeBloc _securityChallengeBloc;
  AdaptiveDialog? _adaptiveLoading;
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _securityChallengeBloc = context.read();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:
            Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.screenTitleVerifyYourIdentity),
      ),
      body: BlocSideEffectListener<SecurityChallengeBloc,
          SecurityChallengeEffect>(
        listener: (context, effect) {
          switch (effect) {
            case final SecurityChallengeEffectShowLoading _:
              _onShowLoadingLoginEffect();
              break;
            case final SecurityChallengeEffectHideLoading _:
              _onHideLoadingLoginEffect();
              break;
           
          }
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<SecurityChallengeBloc, SecurityChallengeState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w, vertical: 32.h),
              children: [
                InputField.text(
                  controller: _textEditingController,
                  label: state.question.question,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _securityChallengeBloc
                        .add(AnswerChangedChallengeEvent(value));
                  },
                ),
                AppSpace.h10,
                PrimaryButton.fixedMedium(
                  'Submit',
                  onPressed: state.isValid
                      ? () {
                          _securityChallengeBloc.add(SubmitChallengeEvent());
                        }
                      : null,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onShowLoadingLoginEffect() {
    _onHideLoadingLoginEffect();
    _adaptiveLoading = AdaptiveDialog.loading(context,
        title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.accessingAccount,
        body: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.pleaseWait);
    _adaptiveLoading?.show();
  }

  _onHideLoadingLoginEffect() {
    _adaptiveLoading?.hide();
  }

  
}
```

the app bar disapear completly

I spect that the app show the app in all moments , and the issue only happens when put on production (test fly) ios